# Total Count of Data in array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a total count of countries entered in my dB.  Obviously some of these are going to be duplicates, so I don't want the total number of rows, but rather the total number of countries.  So for example:

```
Russia -> 5
USA -> 10
Canada -> 6
Mexico -> 12
```

In this data set, the number total I'd be trying to get is 4.

Right now I have this query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(id) AS countCnt, country FROM users GROUP BY country ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC");
```

then I'm iterating through the values of the query:

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $country = $row['country'];
    $countryCount = $row['countCnt'];
    $countries[$country] = $countryCount;
    }
    $country_text = array_keys($countries);
    $country_count = array_values($countries);
```

How would I return the total Count of countries from `$country_text`?  I want to assign this number to the variable $x.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are GROUPing BY country, the number of rows your query returns will be the number of countries. So

```
$x = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: And that completes this: for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {echo "['{$country_text[$i]}'" . "," . "{$country_count[$i]}],";  thanks @Nick.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to do this using subqueries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM(
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS countCnt, country FROM users
    GROUP BY country ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
)
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$country_text = array_unique($countries);
```

Comment: never even heard of that one lol, but I read up in the manual.  I see where your going with it, but I think the above method is easier given my query.  I appreciate the response.  Cheers.